# Google calendar events - Calendar API or Providers?

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

Sorry if this question is kind of vague, but I don't want to start programming before I ask and make a bad choice that I later regret.

Basically, I want the app to get an hour period, then query the google calendar of the currently logged in user (I have Google Sign In already integrated into my app, and I'm guessing I could extract the signed in ID from that quite easily) to see if he is free. I don't want to actually retrieve the events he has; I just want to see if there are any events in that hour period.

I've been reading up on the Calendar API but also Calendar Providers, and I am not sure if I fully understand the differences between the two. For my purposes, listed above, what would be the better choice? I've looked through a few of the questions already posted on this, but most of them tend to be about retrieving events, and I'm just making sure there's no other type of query I could make to the Google Calendar API that might be quicker than retrieving all the events and manually checking.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been reading up on the Calendar API but also Calendar Providers

In short, Calendar API is API you need to access over network (HTTP/S), while [Calendar Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) is a repository on Android for a user's calendar
events, allowing to integrate with Calendar. As it exists locally on your device and is designed to make the whole thing simpler for apps, you should just go for it if you are thinking about integration with your app.

Comment: Alright, thank you. So if I understand it right, the Calendar API would only work if the user were online?

Comment: Yes, you need network access to reach this API. By using Provider you do not, because it's on the device already. Also you do not need to care networking at all as calendar syncing is done by Google code so choice is rather simple :)